# Applying Leibniz's Rule to an Integral With Multiple Parameters

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

I was given the following exercise and wasn't really able to make heads-or-tails out of it. It goes like so:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be **twice differentiable continuously**, and statisfy the following:
\begin{align*}
    \quad & \forall (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \\
    (*) \quad & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y,z)
\end{align*}
Then define:
\begin{gather*}
    g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
    (x,y) \rightarrow \int_0^y f(x,y-z,z)dz
\end{gather*}
Prove for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x,y) + f(x,0,y)
\end{gather*}

I do know this question must involve *Leibniz's Rule of Integration Under The Integral Sign*, yet I am not sure how this is applicable here.
The only sensible step to take is to fix  $g$ for both variables and derive using Leibniz's rule (as we know $g$ is continuously differentiable twice in $\mathbb{R}^3$).
So for the second variable:
\begin{gather*}
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} =  f(y,y,z)\cdot\frac{d}{dy}y + \int_0^y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y-z,z)dz
\end{gather*}
For the first variable it seemed to me that I should derive twice using Leibniz's rule so I can apply $(*)$, and I got:
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} = \int_0^y\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y-z,z)dz
\end{gather*}
We can easily see that by applying $(*)$ we get close to the required term, yet it is not quite there.
I assume my evaluation of $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ is incorrect.

So first and foremost, how would one comprehensively justify using Leibniz's rule here in the preceding manner - it is not your usual case, there are two parameters in the integral represented by $g$. Is it even justifiable here?

And secondly, did I evaluate $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ wrongly, or have I just missed something and the evaluation is incomplete?

Any hint or explanation would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you so much, and have a great day!

Comment: Prior edit: typoEdit: I see the dummy variable outside an integral, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = f(y,y,z)  \cdots$. I think that should be $f(x,0,y)$, which appears in what is to be proven.

Comment: @cohomonoid Thank you for the correction you were absolutely right, miss typed.

Comment: @cohomonoid Thank you once again, I am starting to see my mistakes after looking at the rule's definition once more. What's not clear to me is why the second coordinate in the term $f(x,0,y)$ is zero after applying the Leibniz's rule. Shouldn't it be simply $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I learned differentiation under the integral sign is as follows:
$$ \partial_x \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} F(x,y) dx = F(b(x),y)b'(x) - F(a(x),y) a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \partial_x F(x,y) dx$$
So applying this to $g$:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_y g(x,y) &= \partial_y \int_0^y f(x,y-z,z)dz \\
&= \frac{dy}{dy} f(x,y-y,y) - \frac{d0}{dy} f(x,y-0,z) + \int_0^y \partial_y f(x,y-z,z) dz \\
&= f(x,0,y) + \int_0^y \partial_x^2 f(x,y-z,z) dz \\
\end{align*}
With respect to your comment on why it's not $f(x,y,z)$, you can see above that $f(x,y-z,z)\big|_{z=y} = f(x,0,y)$.

Now we show that the integral in the last line is equal to $\partial_x^2 g$. Note that because the bounds of integration don't depend on $x$ we have
\begin{align*}
\partial_x g(x,y) &= \partial_x \int_0^y f(x,y-z,z)dz \\
&= \frac{dy}{dx} f(x,y-y,y) - \frac{d0}{dx} f(x,y-0,z) +  \int_0^y \partial_x f(x,y-z,z)dz \\
&= \int_0^y \partial_x f(x,y-z,z)dz 
\end{align*}
Doing the same calculation with the second $\partial_x$ shows that it goes through too, so we have
\begin{align*}
    \partial_y g(x,y) &= f(x,0,y) + \int_0^y \partial_x^2 f(x,y-z,z) dz \\
&= f(x,0,y) + \partial_x^2 \int_0^y f(x,y-z,z) dz \\
&= f(x,0,y) + \partial_x^2 g(x,y)
\end{align*}

I hope that helps.